# Laravel pagination using double eager loading

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-5, eager-loading

I'm using the following code in my ForumController:

```
public function boardIndex($id)
{
    $container = ForumBoard::with([
        'topics' => function($query)
            {
                $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
                $query->paginate(10);
            },
        'children' => function($query)
            {
                $query->orderBy('position', 'asc');
            }
        ])->findOrFail($id);

    return view('forum.board.index', compact('container'));
}
```

It works as expected, I can manually paginate by appending `?page=2` to the end of the url, however if I want to render the paginator in my view using `{!! $container->topics->render() !!}` I get the following error:

```
ErrorException in Macroable.php line 81:
Method render does not exist. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\see\resources\views\forum\board\index.blade.php)
```

---

**EDIT:**

Thanks for the help!
Here's my final, working code (it's even using only 4 database queries instead of 5):

```
public function boardIndex($id)
{
    $board = ForumBoard::findOrFail($id);
    $topics = $board->topics()->latest()->paginate(11);
    $children = $board->children()->oldest('position')->get();

    return view('forum.board.index', compact('board', 'topics', 'children'));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find the Paginator instance anywhere.

Apparently when you paginate inside the closure, only the paginated results are stored.

I came up with a solution that in my opinion is not elegant but may prove helpful:

```
<?php
public function index()
{
    $descendantPaginator = null;
    $user = User::with([
        'descendants' => function ($query) use (&$descendantPaginator) {
            $query->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
            $descendantPaginator = $query->paginate(10);
        }
    ])->findOrFail(1);

    return view('home.index', compact('user', 'descendantPaginator'));
}
```

In your view:

```
{!! $descendantPaginator->links() !!}
```

I recommend the following strategy instead:

```
<?php
public function index()
{
    $user = User::findOrFail(1);
    $descendants = $user->descendants()->latest()->paginate(10);
    return view('home.index', compact('user', 'descendants'));
}
```

Then in your view:

```
{!! $descendants->links() !!}
```